# Do Dart classes have a function that can run on initialisation of an object?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a function in Dart that runs as soon as an instance of a class is made (like **init** in Python)?

I have a **bool** in a class that I want to get based on a database and I was thinking of having a method that would run automatically when the object is declared to check the database and set the **bool**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart constructors allow you to run a method in the constructor.

```
class Model {
  Model(){ //write code here}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do, it's called a `constructor` and you can find out all about it in the [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors) on Dart.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it using your class name, for example:

```
class Example{
  final String name;

   Example(String name){
    this.name = name;
   }
 }
```